# Access Slack plugin from Jenkins script console

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I wonder if it's possible to simulate pipeline plugins operation from Jenkins script console. For example the Slack plugin used to send notifications via pipeline job with the command :

> slackSend (color: colorCode, message: summary)

i want to try playing around and see objects and properties. i'm pretty sure its possible with groovy from the Jenkins script console.

Answer (score 0):

I've found it usually requires looking at the source code. In this case, the source is on GitHub at [jenkinsci/slack-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/slack-plugin).

Here are the steps I would do:

- Find where `"slackSend"` is used to describe the step - [in `SlackSendStep .DescriptorImpl`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/slack-plugin/blob/0757425c8482669b59b22faff7813ee841ad32a0/src/main/java/jenkins/plugins/slack/workflow/SlackSendStep.java#L160)
- The type that is described has `@DataboundSetter` and `@DataboundConstructor` which are exposed to the binding (for example [`setColor(String color)`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/slack-plugin/blob/0757425c8482669b59b22faff7813ee841ad32a0/src/main/java/jenkins/plugins/slack/workflow/SlackSendStep.java#L66-L67)
- The [`Descriptor` constructor](https://github.com/jenkinsci/slack-plugin/blob/0757425c8482669b59b22faff7813ee841ad32a0/src/main/java/jenkins/plugins/slack/workflow/SlackSendStep.java#L155) returns the class type of [`SlackSendStep.SlackSendStepExecution`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/slack-plugin/blob/0757425c8482669b59b22faff7813ee841ad32a0/src/main/java/jenkins/plugins/slack/workflow/SlackSendStep.java#L189)
- The has `SlackSendStep.SlackSendStepExecution` type  [some properties that are injected](https://github.com/jenkinsci/slack-plugin/blob/0757425c8482669b59b22faff7813ee841ad32a0/src/main/java/jenkins/plugins/slack/workflow/SlackSendStep.java#L193-L197)
- The step execution is done in [the `run()` method](https://github.com/jenkinsci/slack-plugin/blob/0757425c8482669b59b22faff7813ee841ad32a0/src/main/java/jenkins/plugins/slack/workflow/SlackSendStep.java#L200-L266)

The main parts I notice from looking at the code is that a [`StandardSlackService`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/slack-plugin/blob/0757425c8482669b59b22faff7813ee841ad32a0/src/main/java/jenkins/plugins/slack/StandardSlackService.java) is created with the parameters that are provided to the step and possibly from global Jenkins configuration.

This code can be taken and adjusted a little bit if you want to execute it from the script console because it will be difficult to execute it the same way that the pipeline path takes.

Here is what I consider the relevant code for reference:

```java
SlackService slackService = getSlackService(baseUrl, team, token, tokenCredentialId, botUser, channel);
boolean publishSuccess;
if(step.attachments != null){
    JsonSlurper jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper();
    JSON json = null;
    try {
        json = jsonSlurper.parseText(step.attachments);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        listener.error(Messages.NotificationFailedWithException(e));
        return null;
    }
    if(!(json instanceof JSONArray)){
        listener.error(Messages.NotificationFailedWithException(new IllegalArgumentException("Attachments must be JSONArray")));
        return null;
    }
    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) json;
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
        Object object = jsonArray.get(i);
        if(object instanceof JSONObject){
            JSONObject jsonNode = ((JSONObject) object);
            if (!jsonNode.has("fallback")) {
                jsonNode.put("fallback", step.message);
            }
        }
    }
    publishSuccess = slackService.publish(jsonArray, color);
}else{
    publishSuccess = slackService.publish(step.message, color);
}
if (!publishSuccess && step.failOnError) {
    throw new AbortException(Messages.NotificationFailed());
} else if (!publishSuccess) {
    listener.error(Messages.NotificationFailed());
}
// rest of method...

// ...

//streamline unit testing
SlackService getSlackService(String baseUrl, String team, String token, String tokenCredentialId, boolean botUser, String channel) {
    return new StandardSlackService(baseUrl, team, token, tokenCredentialId, botUser, channel);
}
```

Comment: And then what? The console doesn't recognize "SlackService".

Comment: @kfsone what do you mean _"and then what?"_ The question wasn't too specific about what they wanted to accomplish. What are you expecting to see in the answer?

Comment: The question is about accessing slack from the console. What you've posted is good, but it doesn't really relate back to the console - `This code can be taken and adjusted a little bit if you want to execute it from the script console`

Comment: `This code can be taken and adjusted a little bit...` what can be adjusted?  The script console cannot resolve class `StandardSlackService`, and no amount of adjustment will change that.  Unless, I'm wrong...?